# largest negative real number represented using IEEE floating point

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754, floating-point-conversion, representation

So I want to find the largest negative real number that can be represented using the IEEE-754 floating point.

So far I know the sign bit should be 1, and mantissa is 11111111, and the exponent is 255. I just put them into the formula, then I get
-1.11111111 x 2^128.

The answer is -3.403 x 10^38.

How do I transform what I have into the answer form ?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. What is "answer form"?

Comment: What are you expecting? A code? or the correct answer? or an algorithm?

Comment: "... and mantissa is 11111111, and the exponent is 255. ..." is not correct. and -1.11111111(base2) x 2^128 --> -6.792355...e+38

Comment: just do your math. Multiplicate what you found - if you can't do in memory, use your calculator and type -1.11111111 x 2^128. Which will give you a different number than you are expected.

Comment: 255 exponent is used for infinity and NaN.

Answer (score 4):

From this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) the formula for calculating the value from the bit pattern is

[image]

The largest negative number will have

- sign bit = 1
- mantissa = all 1's
- exponent = 254

<sub>Note that an exponent of 255 is reserved for special cases like infinity and NAN.</sub>

Plugging those values into the formula, we get

[image]

which can be written as

```
value = (-1)(1 + 0.5 + 0.25 + 0.125 + ... + 2^-23)(2^127)
      = (-1)(2)(2^127)  // since the sum is approximately 2
      = -(2^128)    
      = -3.403 x 10^38  // says my calculator
```

Comment: @user2998413: It looks pretty good to me.  What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @user2998413 Aside from maybe considering "largest negative real number" as `-INF`, this answer does well describe finding the largest _finite_ negative [bianry32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).  "IEEE-754 floating point" does have other floating point types with finite values about `-10*pow(10,6144)`.  Other than that, your comment needs explanation.

Comment: @user2998413 It's hard to improve the answer unless you tell me why you think it's wrong.

Comment: Are any of them reserved? Usually it's first and last